# error sending special chars on jquery.Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I would like to know why calling an jquery.Ajax and sending by parameter on data an string like these: `"Z<Z"` = `"String<String"` crashes! I've tryied with others like `|@##~¬//("·$` but there's no problem...

I've solved using encodeUriComponent, but I would like to know why is crashing and if there's another way to solve it.

```
function getData() {
    var code = "Z<Z"
    return { Id : code };
}

function goAjax(){   
    dataSelected = getData();
    $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Action",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataSelected,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert("Ok")
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using ASP.NET on the server which by default doesn't allow you to send such characters. You could disable it. For example if you are using ASP.NET MVC you could decorate the controller action you are posting to with the `[ValidateRequest(false)]` attribute:

```
[ValidateRequest(false)]
public ActionResult Action(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to disable request validation for the entire action, you could only decorate the property on your view model with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Action(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Now you could send those characters only for the `Id` property.